# Operations are valid only if object is in particular state

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have many types of object in my application. All can have the following states : UpToDate, OutOfDate,NotComputed. All operations of the object, are allowable only if the state of the object is UpTodate. If the state of the object is NotComputed or OutOfDate the only allowable operations are Compute and ChangeComputationParams. In the gui, I want to show the actions on the object only if they are allowable. So I have Operation Validatiors object, for each object that return whether the operation on the object should be displayed on the gui. Problem is, everytime I add new operation to some object, I need to go to its OperationValidator class, and add new function there. It must be better way. example :

```
class Object1OperationValidator
{
    Object1OperationValidator(Object1& object1)
    {
       mObject1 = object1;
    }

    bool CanDoCompute()
    {
       return true;
    }

    bool CanDoChangeComputationParams()
    {
       return true;
    }

    bool CanDoOperation1()
    {
       if(mObject1.State() != UpToDate )
          return false;
       else
          return true;        
    }

    .....
    bool CanDoOperationN()
    {
        if(mObject1.State() != UpToDate )
          return false;
       else
          return true;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Could each object implement a reporting interface that lists the operations it supports and whether each action is supportable. Then the GUI could query each object for the actions it supports (perhaps returned as strings or some kind of numeric id constant) and then for each action it could query the object as to whether the action can be performed?

Comment: how complex are the check in CanDoOperation...() ? it only restricts to something like `obj.State() != someState` ?

Comment: For most of the operations checks it only restricts on object states. There are operations that need more checking than state, but they are few at most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templated class with the implementation of Validate functions:

```
template <class T>
void CheckBaseOperations
{
public:
    CheckBaseOperations(T * obj)
        :inst(obj)
    {}

    bool CheckOperation()
    {
        //...
        return inst->State() != X;
    }
public:
    T * inst;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//for generic types
template <class T>
void CheckOperations : public CheckBaseOperations<T>
{
public:
    CheckOperations(T * obj)
        :CheckBaseOperations<T>(obj)
    {}
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
template <> //specific validation for a certain type.
void CheckOperations <YourType> : public CheckBaseOperations<YourType>
{
public:
    CheckOperations(YourType * obj)
        :CheckBaseOperations<YourType>(obj)
    {}

    bool CheckOperationForYourType()
    {
        //...
        return inst->State() != X;
    }
};
```

Also you can have `CheckOperations` specialized for a specific type if you want